# SparkR functions failing in databricks

Tags: sparkr

I'm not an R user, but i've had a need to use SparkR for some analysis and i am trying to run the code below. Are pipes the issue here?

```
table %>%
SparkR::select('station') %>%
SparkR::count_distinct()
```

But got the error message:

Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function ‘count_distinct’ for signature ‘"SparkDataFrame"’

also tried these to no avail.

```
SparkR::select(table, table$STATION) %>% 
SparkR::countDistinct()
```

```
SparkR::select(table, table$STATION) %>% 
SparkR::count_distinct()
```

Comment: Forgive me I have solved my problem. I needed to call SparkR::agg(...)

`table %>%
  SparkR::agg(distinct_count = countDistinct(table$station)) %>%
  display()`

Answer (score 0):

```
select(table, count_distinct(table$STATION))
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**